# Os métodos setDefaultPushCallback e trackAppOpened descontinuados

Tags: android, deprecated

Ao utilizar o Parse, notei que alguns métodos utilizados nos exemplos do próprio site do PARSE estão descontinuados (*deprecated*), dentre eles o `PushService.setDefaultPushCallback` e o `ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened`. Alguém sabe como ficou a substituição destes métodos?

Answer (score 1):

O método `ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent())`, geralmente utilizado no `OnCreate` foi substituído pelo método `ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent())`. Já o método `PushService.setDefaultPushCallback`, utilizado dentro da classe de aplicação (`extends Application`) não teve um método para substituí-lo, mas sim uma implementação da classe `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver`, como segue no exemplo abaixo:

```java
public class Receiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent){
        Log.e("Push", "Aberto");

        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Crie esta classe, lembrando de substituir `MainActivity.class` pela classe que deseja chamar ao abrir a notificação.

Agora, por último, deve-se alterar o *ArdroidManifest*:

Onde era:

```xml
<receiver
        android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Agora fica:

```xml
<receiver
        android:name="pacote.Receiver"
        android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Esta é a substituição dos métodos *deprecated*.